# 120 guests including children - Amounts needed for party catering

Tags: chili-peppers, bulk-cooking

Together with our families, my fiance and I are doing the food for our post wedding party. We have 117 guests including around 15 children.

We are serving the following

- Beef Chili - GF (100 people)
- Veggie Chili - V/VG (17 veggies)
- Creme Fraiche
- Jalapenos
- Bread - French Sticks etc.
- GF Bread
- Butter
- Cheese

We are also having Coleslaw & Potato Salad. A friend who is a caterer is doing that for us so I don't need info on that.

**How much chili should I try to make? How much bread should I buy?** I'm thinking French sticks, in a basket with a bread board/knife so they can chop this up themselves.

Chili etc. will be cooked on the hob in the kitchen and kept warm in slow cookers where guests can help themselves.

This will be a buffet of sorts, nothing being served as such.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice. No matter how accurate you are measuring the food, you have to have alcohol in your head (not physically). People tend to eat less, on the other hand, other people tend to eat more with a glass of wine or beer. No matter what, have the pizza delivery on quick dial. :-)

Comment: Your friend, the caterer, where is he now? If he is doing some part, he probably has an estimate about the other parts.

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/75505/67  ; I'd also recommend https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/54579/67 ; https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/12068/67

Comment: If you end up making too much ... chili freezes really well.

Answer (score 2):

I know that people frown upon recipes on here, but in the book "[Quantity Recipes: From Meals for Many](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1410106519)" by the New York State College for Home Economics, 1945, they recommend a serving size of 3/4 cup, which for 50 to 55 people is:

```
9 lbs ground beef
2 lbs ground pork
1 1/2 cups onions, chopped
1 cup beef dripping or other fat
5 qts kidney beans (#10 can) or 1 3/4 lb dried
5 qts tomatoes (1 1/2 #10 cans)
2 1/2 TB chili powder
5 TB salt
1/2 tsp pepper
3 TB sugar
1/2 lb crackers, broken
```

I personally wouldn't use that recipe (1.5 cups of onions and 2.5TB chili for 11 lbs of meat?), but it should give you an idea of quantity.

You might be better off making a 'normal' batch of your chili recipe and measuring to see how much it makes, but possibly adjusting if it's significantly less than 3oz of meat per serving.

It's also worth noting that chili freezes *really* well.  If you have the freezer space, you might want to make some in advance and freeze it.  (I use 1qt deli containers, which would be 5 1/3 servings by their estimate).  Of course, I'd also freeze it without beans and add them back when reheating (or serve it separately as an option).

Comment: A few other notes : not everyone's good with a knife.  I'd cut that in advance, or see if where you're getting it from can slice it thickly.  You might also consider corn muffins or even corn chips.  Also, make sure to put the vegetarian chili *after* the meat one.  Many people will just grab the first one they come to, or try a little of everything, so if you only make enough vegetarian chili for the vegetarians, they might not get any.